# does echo equal fputs( STDout )?

Tags: php, stream, stdout

Does `echo` equal `fputs( STDOUT )`, or does `echo` write to a different stream? I've used PHP for a while now, but I don't know very well what's actually happening on a lower level.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

According to [PHP's manual page on wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), the answer is No.

> php://output
>
> php://output is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the
>   output buffer mechanism in the same way as print() and echo().

`print` and `echo` write to `php://output` stream, whereas `fputs(STDOUT)` writes to `php://stdout`.

I did a little test:

```
<?php

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
ob_start();

echo "regular echo\n";
fwrite(STDOUT, "writing to stdout directly\n");
fwrite($output, "writing to php://output directly\n");

$ob_contents = ob_get_clean();
print "ob_contents: $ob_contents\n";
```

This script outputs (tested on PHP 5.2.13, windows):

```
writing to stdout directly
ob_contents: regular echo
writing to php://output directly
```

i.e. writing to `STDOUT` directly bypasses ob handlers.

Comment: Where is the usual default place where the output for STDOUT is stored? E.g. STDERR writes to `C:\xampp\apache\logs\error.log` but STDOUT seems to go "missing".

Comment: STDOUT will store in /path/subdirectory/file-store.txt or it uses echo or print