# How to fwrite to web out in PHP

Tags: php

Say I have this cose:

```
function saysomething($msg) {
    $fd = fopen(STDOUT, 'a');
    fwrite($fd, $msg);
    fclsoe($fd);
}
saysomething('test message');
```

That will work from the command line, but not when called as a web page. What do I need to replace the `STDOUT` with, to be able to write to web output?

`echo` outputs equally well when run either way, so I would expect it to be possible, since I can use fwrite to print to stdout. Is there a magic constant or file descriptor number or something that will let me use fwrite on a web page?

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027902/does-echo-equal-fputs-stdout took me about 5 seconds to find it. its exactly what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo 'test message'` instead of your own saysomething().
Or `$fd = fopen('php://output', 'a');` if you prefer your current style.

Comment: Answer I was looking for: `php://output`